# Can we add multiple update statements based on certain conditions in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I want to create a stored procedure in mssql. Based on the input parameters, respective table should get updated. For eg.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_submitex
AS
    @type int,
    @ex_cde varchar(10)
BEGIN
    IF @type = 2 THEN
       UPDATE t1 
       SET code = @ex_cde
 
    ELSE IF @type = 3 THEN
       UPDATE t2 
       SET code = @ex_cde

    ELSE IF @type = 7 THEN
       UPDATE t3 
       SET code = @ex_cde
```

`t1,t2,t3` are three distinct tables.

Is it possible to implement the above requirement (which I have mentioned in IF else statements) in stored procedure?

Not sure if this can work with case statement.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do this - drop the `THEN` though - not needed/allowed. And **NO**, a `CASE` **expression** cannot help you here - it's an **expression** that can return a single, atomic value (out of a number of options) - but it **cannot** be used to execute code blocks based on conditions. Little detail: the `AS` needs to come **after** the parameters (right before the `BEGIN`)

Comment: If you do want to execute multiple statements within an `IF`/`ELSE` then you need to use `BEGIN` and `END`, not `THEN` (as marc_s mentions). Simply removing the `THEN`'s will work here, along with added an `END` and correcting the initial declaration of the Procedure.

Comment: You'll need to use `IF` rather than `CASE`. `CASE` is an expression, not a control flow statement. in T-SQL.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs. Let me try making the changes as mentioned.